# Displaying one index in an array, while storing the entire entry

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

The title could suck, not sure what a good way to explain it is.

This might both be a bad idea, but I'm trying to make a kind of ninite-thing for Linux/Ubuntu. I want a correctly styled name to appear in the list where you check what you want to install, whereas the package name is needed for installation. I have tried to achieve this, but not had much luck.

The menu/interactive bits have been taken from this site. I have only added arrays as options, and a few other modifications. I am very new to this, and it is mainly a project for learning.

```
#!/bin/bash
# customize with your own.

#Packages
filezilla=("FileZilla" "filezilla" "ftp")
nmap=("Nmap" "nmap" "network_tools")
linssider=("LinSSIDer" "linssider" "network_tools")
wireshark=("Wireshark" "wireshark" "network_tools")
atom=("Atom" "atom" "editor")
vim=("Vim" "vim" "editor")
steam=("Steam" "steam" "chat")
streamlink=("Streamlink GUI" "streamlink" "media")
whois=("Whois" "whois" "network_tools")
htop=("Htop" "htop" "monitoring")
traceroute=("Traceroute" "traceroute" "network_tools")


options=(
"${filezilla[0]}"
#echo Network Tools
"${nmap[0]}"
"${linssider[0]}"
"${wireshark[0]}"
"${whois[0]}"
"${htop[0]}"
"${traceroute[0]}"
#echo "Text Editor"
"${atom[0]}"
"${vim[0]}"
#echo "Chat"
"${steam[0]}"
#echo "Media"
"${streamlink[0]}"


#select all in category x
#select all in cat y
)

#render list
clear
menu() {
    echo ""
    echo "What do you want to install:"
    for i in ${!options[@]}; do
        printf "%3d%s) %s\n" $((i+1)) "${choices[i]:- }" "${options[i]}"
    done
    [[ "$msg" ]] && echo "$msg"; :
}

#selecting
prompt="Check an option (again to uncheck, ENTER when done): "
while menu && read -rp "$prompt" num && [[ "$num" ]]; do
    clear
    [[ "$num" != *[![:digit:]]* ]] &&
    (( num > 0 && num <= ${#options[@]} )) ||
    { msg="Invalid option: $num"; continue; }
    ((num--)); msg="${options[num]} was ${choices[num]:+un}checked"
    [[ "${choices[num]}" ]] && choices[num]="" || choices[num]="+"
done

#what was selected
printf "You selected"; msg=" nothing"
for i in ${!options[@]}; do
    [[ "${choices[i]}" ]] && { printf " \n%s" "${options[i]}"; msg=""; }

  echo ${choices[1]}

done
echo "$msg"


#install selected
#sudo apt install -y update ${choices[1]}
```

Comment: What you want is quite unclear. What is the expected output? What is the current output, and what makes you consider it wrong? What is the issue ?

Comment: Sorry, when you get the list of what you chose from the list, I cannot get it to list the package names, rather than the styled/capitalized name. I want to display the lowercase package name, which I then will use to install the stuff. Currently the styled name is what I get. I wonder if this could be because it's only storing the displayed name, and not the array which contains the package/lowercase name in index 1.